# SOL Transaction Fees Inquiry

Tags: transactions, cryptocurrency, solana

Is it possible to code a solana program (smart contract) where the transaction fees that you should pay, i.e., for minting / stacking / swapping tokens within the program you deployed are covered by the program itself?

Answer (score 3):

There is a network fee that cannot be covered by the program itself. At the time of writing, this fee is 5000 lamports per signature.

If you're talking about swap fees, there is a possibility to pay those fees with a separate account owned by the program, but that logic must be written on the program itself.

Comment: By any chance you got any documentation for that last part? Thank you!

Comment: @Unkown did you find any solution?